# Magento2 Catalog Product Options

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, custom-options

We found this issue when working in a default **Magento2.1**.

While creating **customizable options** for a product, if I select the drop-down field a **second time**, the **spinner never stop** loading.

Please find the below screen-shot:
[image]

I think this is a **Magento2** core bug, can anyone confirm and suggest how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Go the page, open inspector (right click -> inspect element), do the action that causes spinner to stay and check console and network tab for errors.

Comment: Yes, thanks for reply, i visted the inspector network itsays press F5.

Comment: Its worked after first time dropdown selection, but my issue is why second time not working

Comment: You should either see some error in the console or error in XHR request for the data in network tab. If you see the second then you should have some info by clicking on that request and checking `Respnse` tab. If you see nothing in both then you need to start digging inside js files as there might be some custom overwrite that breaks the functionality.

Comment: Can you Please send me the location of js file, iam new to magento2

Comment: I checked clean installation on 2.1.7 with sample data and this tab looks completely different on my installation (check: https://prnt.sc/fw0cvq). It seems that you have some modules that add `Tab Header` and `One Time` fields. I do not have any loader in that place when changing the type. Either those fields were removed and section rebuild or your customization there is faulty. Either way I have no idea which file to look.

Comment: For first time selection of dropdown is ok, now select  type field or file after that select again dropdown field. you can seen the issue clearly.

Comment: No, it's not happening on my installation. As I mentioned your installtion have fields I don't see on my clean 2.1.7 install. If you have version 2.1.7 then you have some modifications which I am not aware of.

Comment: Thanks Zefiryn for your patience, Just now i installed the magento217 now checked the same i am getting same issue.

Comment: Please find the steps followed in the screenhot:http://prntscr.com/fwkrc5

Comment: The issues are with all select fields:(drop down,Radio, checkbox, multiple select)

Comment: I noticed spinner when selecting dropdown, clicking add value, then changing type and after that returning to dropdown. I will try to investigate this in the evening.

Comment: I got nothing. This is indeed some bug in magento code. When you change type with some values in the grid and then return to those type spinner is by set to true but I cannot locate the place. I noticed that if you remove all values and then change type, the return will not cause problems.

Comment: Yes, the bug is in magento

Comment: hi @shiva please check this link not yet fixed  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10291

Comment: Try compiling and deploying static content

Comment: We have tried all the commands @DevAnd

Comment: Currently they are working

Comment: @shivashankarIt is working fine with Magento 2.1.7

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of Magento, similar behaviour in the backend would have been down to a mod_security error being triggered. It's worth investigating this as you may need to whitelist. You can check logs by following [this info](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/analyzing-mod-security-logs/).